# Spring Security authentication manager problems

Tags: java, spring

I have the following entities in my applicacion(User and Role)

The entity user

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Role role;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}
```

The entity role

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String role;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Set<User> userRoles;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<User> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

}
```

This is my authentication manager , I am sure that I have the problem here.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query=
                                   "select username,password from users where username=?"
                           authorities-by-username-query=
                                   "select user_id, role_id from user_roles where user_id =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I have a problem with formation of sql sentence , could anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am recommending a better way to implement Security using spring hibernate concept.

Feel free to ask.

Security xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <import resource="servlet-context.xml"/>

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/register/**" access="permitAll()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/saveLocation" access="permitAll()"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/addFriend" access="permitAll()"/>

        <security:form-login  login-page="/login?error=0"
                     username-parameter="userName"
                     password-parameter="password"
                     authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
                     authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1" />

        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied"/>

        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

        <security:headers>
            <security:cache-control/>
        </security:headers>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthenticator">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customSuccessHandler" class="com.mycompany.lts.security.CustomSuccessHandler"></bean>

    <bean id="userAuthenticator" class="com.mycompany.lts.security.UserAuthenticator"></bean>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.mycompany.lts.security.LogoutSuccessHandler"></bean>
</beans>
```

***UserAuthenticator.java***

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import com.mycompany.lts.entities.UserDetail;
import com.mycompany.lts.exception.MyException;
import com.mycompany.lts.service.UserService;
public class UserAuthenticator implements UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
UserDetail entity = null;
System.out.println(" LOAD BY USER NAME ---- LOADING USERS ");
try {
entity = userService.getUserByUserName(username);
} catch (MyException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new User(entity.getUserName(), entity.getPassword(),
Arrays.asList(authority));
return userDetails;
}

}
```

Executing query:

```
@Override
public UserDetail getUserByUserName(String userName) throws MyException {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return (UserDetail) session.createCriteria(UserDetail.class).add(Restrictions.eq("userName", userName))
                .uniqueResult();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it posible to config with XML ? because I am trying to do all configuration with XML , could you provide a link that can help to me ? Regards!

Comment: i have shared answer having XML configuration with java support. which i feel is ideal way
i share my security xml for your reference with another answer